# What exactly does a .net core api return to the browser?

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

So I have this endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
   var ext = new ApiExtensions();
   List<Record> records = await ext.GetRecords();    
   return Ok(records);
}
```

This is the Record object:

```
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Inspecting the results in Fiddler or Postman I get what I expect to see.
But both of these tools (Fiddler and Postman) give me the ability to "see" the data (body) returned by the api in different formats: text, raw, json, xml, etc. So, what exactly is the api returning to the client? Is it just the "raw" data as displayed in the raw tab? Or does it return the same data in different formats and it is up to the client to use the right one?

(I'm using .net core 3.1.)

Thanks.

Comment: well, .netcore at least from 2.2 APIs return json by default, however you can configure the api to return xml in the startup. i think fiddler and postman just tries its best to parse the JSON into xml when you select it. If you notice its not proper xml, its still a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Core MVC/API has support for formatting response data. Response data can be formatted using specific formats or in response to client requested format. The built-in helper method [Ok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok) returns **JSON-formatted** data:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetMovie()
    {
        return Ok(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
    }
```

You can using the F12 browser developer tools or Postman to check the response header, `content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8` is displayed.

[image]

More detail information about response data format, see [Format response data in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

> But both of these tools (Fiddler and Postman) give me the ability to
> "see" the data (body) returned by the api in different formats: text,
> raw, json, xml, etc

About the Fiddler and PostMan response body format, I think it is the tool's function, it is better to change the response body format.